# TreeSet in java not displaying data properly

Tags: java, tostring

```
public class Book {
    String title;

    public Book(String t) {
        title = t;
    }
}

public class Bookcomparator implements Comparator<Book> {
    public int compare(Book one, Book two) {
        return (one.title.compareTo(two.title));
    }
}

public class TreesetTest {
    public void go() {
        Book b1 = new Book("How");
        Book b2 = new Book("Remix");
        Book b3 = new Book("Finding ");

        Bookcomparator bc = new Bookcomparator();
        TreeSet<Book> set = new TreeSet<Book>(bc);
        set.add(b1);
        set.add(b2);
        set.add(b3);

        System.out.println(set);
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TreesetTest t = new TreesetTest();
        t.go();
    }
}
```

when I run this prog it displays

```
[first.Book@c2ea3f, first.Book@a0dcd9, first.Book@1034bb5]
```

Please somebody help me.

Answer (score 6):

You must override `toString()` method in your `Book` class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.title;
}
```

or experiment with something fancier:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "[Book: title='" + this.title + "']";
}
```

The default implementation found in [`Object.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) prints not very useful `first.Book@c2ea3f`.